# PHP DOMDocument, retrieve just content of a div, without div tag

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using DOMDocument to retrieve on a HTML page a special div.

I just want to retrive the content of this div, without the div tag.

For example :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($webtext['content']);
$main = $dom->getElementById('inter');
$dom->saveHTML()
```

Here, i have the result :

```
<div id="inter">
//SOME THINGS IN MY DIV
</div>
```

And i just want to have :

```
//SOME THINGS IN MY DIV
```

Ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Read **manual**: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#101243

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to go with simple does it.  You already have:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($webtext['content']);
$main = $dom->getElementById('inter');
$dom->saveHTML();
```

Now, [`DOMDocument::getElementById()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) returns **one** [`DOMElement`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) which extends [`DOMNode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) which has the `public string` *`nodeValue`*. Since you don't specify if you are expecting anything but text within that `div`, I'm going to assume that you want anything that may be stored in there as plain text.  For that, we are going to remove `$dom->saveHTML();`, and instead replace it with:

```
$divString = $main->nodeValue;
```

With that, `$divString` will contain `//SOME THINGS IN MY DIV`, which, from your example, is the desired output.

If, however, you want the HTML of the inside of it and not just a String representation - replace it with the following instead:

```
$divString = "";
foreach($main->childNodes as $c) 
    $divString .= $c->ownerDocument->saveXML($c);
```

What that does is takes advantage of the inherited [`DOMNode::childNodes`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) which contains a [`DOMNodeList`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) each containing its own DOMNode (for reference, see above), and we loop through each one getting the `ownerDocument` which is a [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and we call the [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) function.  The reason we pass the current `$c` node in to the function is to prevent an entire valid document from being outputted, and because the `ownerDocument` is what we are looping through - we need to get one child at a time, with no children left behind. *(sorry, it's late, couldn't resist.)*

Now, after either option, you can do with `$divString` what you will.  I hope this has helped explain the process to you and hopefully you walk away with a better understanding of what is going on instead of rote copying of code just because it works. ^^

Comment: I just tried this with saveXML() but it still contains my <span> elements :(

Comment: @bluppfisk Yes, it would, as it is intended to do. If you don't, please re-read the answer to get the output you desire. ^^

Comment: sorry, I made myself not very clear. I meant that I was doing $dom->getElementById('span') and found that the 'span' element itself was still included when I then used savedXML. I _do want_ all other HTML to be preserved, so nodeValue is no option, but not the tag. How would I go about stripping it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

```
 $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

foreach($xpath->query('//div[@id="inter"]/*') as $node)
{
  $node->nodeValue
}
```

or simplu you can edit your code. [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

```
$main = $dom->getElementById('inter');

echo  $main->nodeValue
```

Comment: Just want to point out that your second code block doesn't work. `$main` will be one [`DOMElement`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) at that point and can't be iterated through.

Comment: I would welcome you to try it, even if you do assign `$node->nodeValue` to something in that loop, there is nothing there, the loop never runs. =]  Please read [`getElementById`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) for reference, if you used [`getElementsByTagName`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) that would work as it gives a [`DOMNodeList`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php). ^^

Comment: yes you are right .. but the point is in our case $main will have one value then why cant you iterate it ... ?

Comment: Because there's nothing to iterate through, the `DOMNode` doesn't behave as a single item array as a single tag would with `GetElementsByTagName` ^^

Answer (score 0):

you can use my custom function to remove extra div from content

```
    $html_string = '<div id="inter">
        SOME THINGS IN MY DIV
    </div>';
```

// custom function

```
function DOMgetinnerHTML($element) 
{ 
   $innerHTML = ""; 
   $children = $element->childNodes; 
   foreach ($children as $child) 
   { 
      $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
      $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
      $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
   } 
   return $innerHTML; 
}
```

your code will like

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$innerHTML_contents = DOMgetinnerHTML($divs->item(0));
echo $innerHTML_contents
```

**and your output will be**

```
SOME THINGS IN MY DIV
```

Comment: Except it isn't your function, you got it from http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#89718  Don't claim something is yours when you copy a function line for line from elsewhere.